# Why does firstOrFail change the results of this query?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

Why does `firstOrFail()` cause the results of this eloquent query to change?

```
>>> Organization::find('300048');
=> Models\Organization {#889
     id: 300048,
     token: "redacted",
     name: "DAYJK4EGPE",
     domain: null,
     created_at: "2017-05-19 17:42:55",
     updated_at: "2017-05-19 17:42:56",
     stripe_customer_id: "redacted",
     referral_snippet: null,
     primary_business: null,
   }
>>> Organization::find('300048')->firstOrFail();
=> Models\Organization {#897
     id: 300033,
     token: "redacted",
     name: "123456",
     domain: "google.com",
     created_at: "2017-05-17 13:24:23",
     updated_at: "2017-05-24 15:50:25",
     stripe_customer_id: "redacted",
     referral_snippet: null,
     primary_business: null,
   }
>>>
```

The model with id `300033` is the first in my database, but I expected it to still return the organization with id `300048`, since that was the only result in the collection `firstOrFail()` is being called on.

Comment: I could change it to `where('id', '300048')->firstOrFail()` but that seems silly. I want to use `find()`.

Comment: D'oh, I need to use `findOrFail()`...

Comment: please post this as an answer to your own questions since it might help others.

Comment: @milo526 Done, hopefully my stupidity saves someone a few minutes down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've figured it out yourself, but essentially `firstOrFail` is going to grab the first record when you use a `where`, if you don't use a `where` clause it will just get the first record in the DB.

As you've figured out, you need [`findOrFail`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) in order to find the first record with that ID, or fail.

Answer (score 2):

You should use use `Organization::findOrFail('300048');`.

See the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) for more information on throwing exceptions.